# Flickering Frequency Analysis using Python + OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, frequency-analysis

I have a video of a light source that is flickering.  I'd like to figure out what frequency it is flickering at.  My basic idea is to go frame-by-frame and take the average of the brightness of a certain group of pixels.  I can graph it and run a Fourier transform to find the frequency.

I've never used OpenCV and Python together before but I did some initial research on going frame-by-frame:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

I've also done a bit of work with Fourier transforms in Python and I believe I could use numpy to achieve this, however, I don't know how to get the pixel brightnesses in the first place.

Thanks, Noah

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access pixel values in order to do this. You can use `cv2.mean()` to get the mean value of image pixels, it also operates with a mask if you want only part of the image.

when using python with OpenCV the image is just a numpy arrat so you can access pixel values vey easily `pixel = image[x][y]`

Comment: Should I be able to use this with the example I previously gave on getting the image frame-by-frame?

Comment: Yes, you should. I assume you should use the image 'gray' in the example